# Cómo guardar datos en tablas distintas

Tags: php, laravel, tablas

tengo esta función store:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    DB::beginTransaction();

    try {
        
        $pedido = Pedido::create([
            'id_usuario' => Auth()->user()->id,
            'id_empleado' => $request->get('id_empleado')
        ]);

        $items = Cart::getContent();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            DetallePedido::create([
                'id_producto' => $item->id,
                'id_pedido' => $pedido->id,
                'quantity' => $item->quantity
            ]);
        }
        
        DB::commit();

        Cart::clear();

    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        DB::rollback();
        return redirect()->route('pedidos.index')->with('error', 'No se registro la venta, verifique los datos antes de registrar la venta');
    }

    return redirect()->route('pedidos.index')->with('success', 'Se registró la venta');
}
```

utilizando `dd()` puedo ver que sí me trae los datos que quiero que se guarden, el problema es que por alguna razón no me crean nada en las dos tablas `pedidos` y `detalle_pedidos` y según los ejemplos que estoy revisando es así, por lo que no logro encontrar el error.

Luego de probar la función sin el `try` el error que me aparece es: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'quantity' doesn't have a default value`

Al utilizar `dd($items)` luego del `DetallePedido::create` dentro de la función me trae lo siguiente:

```
  #items: array:2 [▼
    1 => Darryldecode\Cart\ItemCollection {#1459 ▼
      #items: array:5 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "descripcion" => "cosa1"
        "quantity" => "4"
        "attributes" => Darryldecode\Cart\ItemAttributeCollection {#1460 ▶}
        "conditions" => []
      ]
    }


    3 => Darryldecode\Cart\ItemCollection {#1461 ▼
      #items: array:5 [▼
        "id" => 3
        "descripcion" => "cosa3"
        "quantity" => "3"
        "attributes" => Darryldecode\Cart\ItemAttributeCollection {#393 ▶}
        "conditions" => []
      ]
```

Comment: Hola Karelix, Revisa bien tu sintaxis, esas comas te van a dar un dolor de cabeza. `'quantity' => $item->quantity,`  y `'id_empleado' => $request->get('id_empleado'),` no deben ponerse si ya no vas a listar otro parámetro

Comment: ya eliminé esas comas, siempre me pasa, tengo que estar más pendiente; aún no me guarda nada :/

Comment: en otro post habiamos quedado en que esta no es la forma de acceder a las propiedades:  $item->quantity ...

Comment: te recomiendo quitar los try catch y la transaction, (a modo de prueba) solo para ver si hay un error que te este generando, asi detectas en que línea esta

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 en este caso es porque me lo estoy trayendo desde los items, ¿no sería de esa forma?

Comment: @HeynerMartinez el error que me da es `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'quantity' doesn't have a default value`, pero utilizando `dd($items)` sí existe el quantity, entonces no entiendo muy bien porque si sí me trae el `id_producto` con `$item->id` ¿por qué no el quantity?

Comment: que te dice la traduccion del error???

Comment: dentro del foreach antes del:  DetallePedido::create([ intenta colocar el dd($item) para ver que estas pasando ... a lo  mejor necesitas algo como: foreach ($items as $key => $item) {

Comment: Agregué el `dd($items)`, voy a probar con un `foreach ($items as $key => $item)` a ver

Comment: Pues nada de lo que intento sirve, genuinamente no sé qué más hacer

Comment: Bueno lo que me da a pensar que el campo quantiry talvez esta escrito de forma diferente en tu BD revisa eso tambien, porque si decís que si haces un dd, quantity si va debe haber algo mas escrito

Comment: Un poco tarde pero el problema es que no estaba referenciando el ``quantity`` en el modelo; de igual forma terminé cambiando casi todo el proceso